# How to create a isolated "environment" in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

Is there any way to create a isolated environment in Ubuntu 14.04? I have a unstable application installed and sometimes it doesn't work, I don't know why. So, I'm trying to make a isolate environment, in a way that the dependencies I install will be available only in this environment (something like python virtual environment).

The program needs these dependencies to be installed: **libc6**, **libstdc++6,** **imagemagick**, **perl**, **libgl1-mesa-glx**, and **libglu1-mesa**

I hope you have understood my question. Thank you!

Comment: Docker - https://www.docker.com/what-docker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/what-docker) to create an isolated environment similar to a VM. You would have the have the Docker daemon running on your development machine (available on Mac, Windows, and Linux). You then create a `Dockerfile` that starts with the Ubuntu 14.04 base image. You can then use the Docker syntax to write commands to install your dependencies, and copy your code into the Docker container (instance of your isolated environment).

So let's say you have a basic java app and you are in the `/app` directory:

```
/app
|
├── /bin
|   └── app.jar
|
├── /src
|   └── app.java
|
└── Dockerfile
```

Your `Dockerfile` would look as follows to describe your isolated environment:

```
# Use the Ubuntu 14.04 base image
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Install dependencies 
# (assuming they are available via apt-get)

# <install Java here>

RUN apt-get install -y \
libc6                  \
libstdc++6             \
imagemagick            \
perl                   \
libgl1-mesa-glx        \ 
libglu1-mesa       

# Copy code (or binaries) into the container
COPY app/bin/app.jar /app.jar

# Expose port 8080
EXPOSE 8080

# Run the application
CMD java -jar app.jar
```

You then need to `build` an image from the `Dockerfile` with the build command:

```
docker build -t app .
```

Then run it (let's say it exposes port 8080):

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 app
```

Now your app will be available at `localhost:8080` on your development machine, but it will be running in an isolated Ubuntu container.

Comment: My program works with images, can I run a docker container with this program and use images that are out of the container?

Comment: @Julio What do you mean by that? As in have this containerized application interact with other processes on your host computer that are not in the docker application? Short answer, no. if that were the case then the environment would not be isolated. But, assuming you have some app on a public port open, the app in the docker container should be able to see it over the network. However, the loopback address 127.0.0.1 in the container is not the same as 127.0.0.1 (localhost) of the host machine. Look up networking with docker, as I believe you can do binding, but I have no experience with that.

Comment: I have this image editor (the program I was talking about) and I need to isolate this, because I think the program get corrupted because other people use the same computer I use. So, they may install other programs and it modifies the dependencies that my program needs. Because of this, I want to isolate my program, this way the dependencies will never change its version. The usage of the program is by terminal, like this: $ register image1 image2 . Do you think Docker is a good solution? Thank you.

Comment: I thought you meant a "Docker image." If you plan to "expose" this program as a service, then yes. That is, for example if it can upload / download photos over HTTP connection, sure. But, if it is something you use by hand, no. It is possible, but you would have to SSH into the docker container each time you wanted to use it, and SCP the files into and out of the docker container to actually access the edited files. A better solution might be a VM with VirtualBox and have a shared folder between the host and guest OS. This can be accomplished with docker too by binding a directory.